# Laravel 5.6 spatie/laravel-sitemap generates the default xml line and no routes

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

Can anyone please help me?

Hi. I have tried using Console command to generate the sitemap.xml.
It always generate the default sitemap.xml file.

```
` urlset xmlns=" http: //www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 " `

` xmlns:xhtml = " http: //www.w3.org/1999/xhtml "`
```

I then tried to use it manually in my routes in order to check whether there is a problem with console command.

It generated the same default xml again.

I thought there might be something wrong with my routes. I then added simple routes like.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', function() {
return view('welcome');
});
```

But still it generated that same default xml both from console command and from visiting a route.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my docker environment. I used laragon on windows, which perfectly create the sitemap.

For google seo kindly do remove dynamic routes from sitemap.

Comment: Hey. Facing the same problem. Changing the environment does not seem to be a good solution though.

Comment: Can you please share more details about it?
Which development environment are you using?

Comment: I am also using docker,  a bit updated version by my company but it should not matter

Comment: Have a look at the following. This might help you. I didn't get official 

https://github.com/danielemoraschi/sitemap-app