# Laravel sitemap generator output empty file

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-sitemap

I have installed a fresh Laravel (v 6.7) project and then installed this package [spatie/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap#postcardware). So then as in the documentation I have added below code into my route file web.php file

```
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

Route::get('/sitemap', function () {
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 5 minutes
SitemapGenerator::create('http://sandrianaplantations.com/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
return 'completed';
});
```

Then when I check sitemap.xml file it has below content

```
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
<loc>http://sandrianaplantations.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-17T06:35:43+00:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

But if I generate the site map for above url via [XML-sitemap.com](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/details-sandrianaplantations.com-922a2db5e.html) it generate below content

```
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!--
 created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com 
-->
<url>
<loc>https://sandrianaplantations.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-17T06:33:44+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://sandrianaplantations.com/About-us/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-17T06:33:44+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://sandrianaplantations.com/Gallery/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-17T06:33:44+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://sandrianaplantations.com/Contacts/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-17T06:33:44+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

So could anyone please tell me if Im making any mistakes in my route file.(web.php) .I have gone through there official document. But nothing can be found. Also gone through YouTube too. Also below questions were almost checked.

[question 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074213/spatie-laravel-sitemap-generated-xml-file-is-empty)

[question 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259597/laravel-5-6-spatie-laravel-sitemap-generates-the-default-xml-line-and-no-routes)

Answer (score 0):

note :  this package generate other site not self site!
but have a trick in doc package

> spatie/laravel-sitemap
>   Configuring the crawler
>   The crawler itself can be configured to do a few different things.

Comment: Hey @Sajjad I dont think this is about the path. Also I have tested this too. Nothing changed

Comment: ops  i install this package and  have same problem !!!
but "http://sandrianaplantations.com/"  change other site its work !!! i guess not self crawling and generate sitemap

Comment: changed the url and also checked error log. But still same